# How to dowload .shp of disctricts (areas) in Overpass turbo?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I need download OSM-data. More precisely, I need to download data on the subject of the Russian Federation.
For example i can make key "building in Kemerovo". And it works. But how make Kemerovo Oblast (District)? I don't understand.

But how make Kemerovo Oblast (District)? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard explains how this works:

*If a string (for example the value of one of the tag-selectors above) contains whitespace or other special characters (such as colons, dashes, non-ascii characters, etc.) it must be enclosed in quotes:*

```
building in "Kemerovo Oblast (District)"
```